# Three.js how can I load a Preview STL over https? Default loader is giving mixed content errors

Tags: javascript, three.js, mixed-content

Ok, I am trying to build a quick print quotation system for my site, a preview here https://www.instagram.com/p/BsOr6cCjw7Q/,

I have gotten all working but with it pushed to the site, I get this error,

```
"Mixed Content: The page at 'https://taibhsedesigns.ie/3dprintcalc/3d.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.taibhsedesigns.com/404.html'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
```

Ive traced the error to be caused by the following,

```
  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
            loader.load('adam.stl', function(geometry) {


                default_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                default_mesh.receiveShadow = true;
                default_mesh.castShadow = true;


                scene.add(default_mesh);

            });
```

It seems the loader makes a http request for the file rather than https, how can I resolve this as I dont see anything in the documents to force https or an alternative loader that will carry out such over https?

Any help or guidance would be very much appreciated as I am still new to Three.js and this is one last hurdle I am struggling with.

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to the STLLoader? Why is it requesting a 404 page?

Comment: I'm positive it's related as when I remove this code block all works fine, the STL file is available within the folder the code is and as for the 404 that may be due to how my htaccess file is configured as I've tried setting the site to redirect any non found Content to that page.

Comment: Right but the 404 load is very fishy -- I'd look at your network tab and make sure it's loading the URL you think it is.